# Аналог QSettings

Tags: python

есть ли аналог QSettings во встроенных средствах python для записи параметров в реестр Windows?
сейчас пользуюсь только Tkinter...

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/winreg.html

Comment: а как задать цвет для рамки кнопки при наведении мыши в Tkinter Button?

Comment: Задайте другой вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

[WinReg](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/winreg.html) :

> These functions expose the Windows registry API to Python. Instead of using an integer as the registry handle, a handle object is used to ensure that the handles are closed correctly, even if the programmer neglects to explicitly close them.